# Modal RadWindow with vb.net and WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, web-applications, radwindow

When I try to open a modal Radwindow (VB.NET, WPF, Web Application) with this code:

```
Dim x as new RadWindow
x.content = MyContenctControl (UserControl)
x.Owner = me
x.ShowDialog
```

The line 3 give me an error with the implicit object from VB.NET (Me)

> Error 1 Value of type 'myProject.Main' can not be converted to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl'. C: \ .... \ Projects \
>   MyProject \ MyProject \ Main.xaml.vb 100 57 myProject

how I can afford it, so the main form (Me) can be passed by value "ByVal" method and this in turn assigned to the Owner property of Radwindow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
x.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
```